# Python: Rationale for behavior of assigning '' to list slice

Tags: python

I usually use numpy that automatically broadcasts in many cases, and got baffled by the behavior of similar code using lists in base python.

Numpy case

```
aa = np.zeros((10)).astype('U')
aa[0:5] = ''
aa
# array(['', '', '', '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0'], dtype='<U32')
```

What I tripped on in base Python

```
bb = ['0.0']*10
bb[0:5] = ''
bb
# ['0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
```

Note: It shortens the list!!
What I should have done

```
cc = ['0.0']*10
cc[0:5] = ['']*5
cc
# ['', '', '', '', '', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
```

I get that lists dont broadcast stuff and does things elementwise. Probably good to keep that consistent. But why doesnt `bb[0:5] = ''` just throw an error?
`bb[0:5] = None` would have made some sense, but *that* instead throws me TypeError.

`bb[0:5] = ''` described in words becomes something like,
"replace the first half of this list with an empty string". But it doesnt make sense to replace part of a list with a string. They are different types.
`type('')` returns `<class 'str'>`.

Could someone enlighten me on why things are implemented like this? Has to be a good reason that I dont understand.

Comment: A string a sequence of characters. The empty string is an empty sequence. So `bb[0:5] = ''` means "put an empty sequence in place of the slice `0:5`". Same as `bb[0:5] = []`.

Comment: The key insights here are 1) a string is iterable (try `bb[0:5] = 'ab'`) and `None` is not, and 2) normal Python lists don't default to doing things array-wise the way numpy arrays do.